# Adding an extension to the blog post pages on liferay

Tags: url-rewriting, liferay, blogs, liferay-6

My problem is i want to add '.html' extension to my every blog post. For example right now i have a blog post url 'http://www.indu.com/blog/-/blogs/creating-a-custom-portlet-in-liferay' and what i want is 'http://www.indu.com/blog/-/blogs/creating-a-custom-portlet-in-liferay.html'

I would be grateful if any one can help?

Comment: like Advaita has pointed it out, I'm curious to know why you want to do that ? There is absolutely no impact on seo adding .html at the end of url.

Comment: Jerome its our clients requirement to have .html extension in all the the pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why would you want this.

Anyways, I think you can change the `urlTitle` field of `BlogsEntry` and append `.html` to the string. May be use a service-wrapper-hook to append `.html` to the `urlTitle` whenever a blog is created or updated.

Or you can even use a `ModelListener` if it exists for BlogsEntry hook to update the blog's `urlTitle` by using `onCreate` & `onUpdate` methods.

**Edit**

The `urlTitle` field is present in the `BlogsEntry` table.

You can access this in java with the following methods:

```
BlogsEntry blog = BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.getBlogsEntry(90989); // retrieves the blog-entry

String blogUrlTitle = blog.getUrlTitle(); 

blog.setUrlTitle(blogUrlTitle + ".html"); // this would set the string
```

You can have a check for the `blogUrlTitle` so that you don't have repeated `.html` appended to the string:

```
if (!blogUrlTitle.contains(".html")) { // append only if the title does not contain `.html`
    blog.setUrlTitle(blogUrlTitle + ".html");
}
```

You can refine your code as you like, the above is just a guide-line.

As a side-note, I would always try to reason with the client why they want something, this helps not only to fend-off bad-change-requests but also helps in giving an alternative to the client (which is less taxing on the developers like us **;-)** ). In most cases this helps to understand the client's business better & provide better returns.

Comment: Thanks for your help Advaita, but can you please guide me where can i find the urlTitle field of BlogsEntry defined??